# run initial commands in a docker-compose service

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I followed [this](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/) tutorial to run my django web-app locally, apart for the web-app the only service is a postgres db.

I wrote a simple script `entrypoint.sh` to automate the initial operations needed by a django app, like `migrate, makemigrations, collectstatic, createsuperuser`;

Everything works fine, except that `entrypoint.sh` runs everytime I use `docker-compose up`, performing initial operations that should only run once.

How can I set up my `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml` so that `entrypoint.sh` is run just the first time and not everytime I `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up` again?

Dockerfile

```
# importing base image
FROM python:3.9

# updating docker host or host machine
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# changing current working directory to /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copying requirement.txt file to present working directory
COPY requirements.txt ./

# installing dependency in container
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copying all the files to present working directory
COPY . .

# informing Docker that the container listens on the
# specified network ports at runtime i.e 8000.
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  app:
    build: ./
    command: gunicorn sial.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/usr/src/app/data/
      - ./media/:/usr/src/app/media/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=admin@email.it
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin@email.it
      - DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=passadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 manage.py migrate;

python3 manage.py makemigrations;

python3 manage.py migrate;

python3 manage.py collectstatic --clear;

python3 manage.py createsuperuser --no-input;

gunicorn sial.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000;
```

RECAP

In the directory where my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file are:

1. `sudo docker-compose build app`
2. `sudo docker-compose up` -> initial migrations are applied, static files are collected, superuser created
3. `sudo docker-compose down`
4. `sudo docker-compose up` -> initial migrations are applied, static files are collected, superuser created AGAIN. I'm trying to avoid this.

I'm new to docker-compose and any help is really appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have your entrypoint script create a flag file. Check for the existence of that file when the script starts, and skip the initialization logic if it does.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty but simple way would be to ignore the error of the `createsuperuser` command by changing it to `python3 manage.py createsuperuser --no-input || true;`.

This might even be the solution you prefer, because if the variables for docker-compose change, a new superuser would be created with the changed values.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

python3 manage.py migrate;

python3 manage.py makemigrations;

python3 manage.py migrate;

python3 manage.py collectstatic --clear;

python3 manage.py createsuperuser --no-input || true;

gunicorn sial.wsgi:application --workers=2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000;
```