# dockerized django build : how to run only once createsuperuser

Tags: django, docker

I have a django docker container for the backend on my website. There is a volume for the database so i can save the database even if i change the backend configuration.

I have tried to put the createsuperuser in my Dockerfile and in a script launched with "command" in docker-compose. In the Dockerfile, the problem is the prompt is not connected to the database...
In the script, the command is re-run each time the container is started

I would like this command to be run only once, but i dont know how to proceed.

The problem is the container is rebuilt in my ci/cd pipeline if i change the configuration files, and so the command is re-run.

I have seen this post [Run command in Docker Container only on the first start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836764/run-command-in-docker-container-only-on-the-first-start) but that also works only if the container is not rebuilt.

A workaround with a createsuperuser command that would fail would work and that seemed to be the case with django previous versions (before version 4) but i now have "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username" error which tells me the command seems to be run multiple times and gives me errors in the database...

Comment: if you have to create super at once why would you put in the dockerfile? Create superuser after container has been deployed by `docker exec -it container_name bash` and run `python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: I want to automate this in scripts in can reuse in many deployments where i change the files

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to run `createsuperuser` based on those variables.

If you ignore the return value of the command, it doesn't matter whether the superuser already exists or not. Additionally, you would benefit from being sure that the defined superuser always exists.

And if you change the environment variables, the superuser will be recreated with the changed values.

See similar question here: [run initial commands in a docker-compose service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72857022/run-initial-commands-in-a-docker-compose-service/72858003#72858003)

Comment: thank you, that is a good way to do, however, im not sure i have an error with createsuperuser run twice in django 4 as my error is a duplicate auth_user.username...i will try it tough